# How to build search request to Solr (sunspot) with nested includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Rails 4.2.8.
Solr
Sunspot

The original request is

```
@orders = current_user
  .customer
  .orders
  .includes(
    address: { delivery_zone: :franchise },
    restaurant_orders: { restaurant: :franchise },
    ordered_items: :menu_item
  )
  .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Solr search request is

```
@orders = Order.search do
  fulltext params[:query] if params[:query]
  with :customer_id, current_user.customer.id
  order_by :id, params[:sort] || :desc
  paginate :page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10
```

How can I re-build Solr search request to add

```
  .includes(
    address: { delivery_zone: :franchise },
    restaurant_orders: { restaurant: :franchise },
    ordered_items: :menu_item
  )
```

Thanks in advance.